# Faild to settext in textview.Error:-android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0

Tags: java, android

First of all, I am a beginner at android. I am actually trying to build a quiz app. but I am getting stuck with an error that is unexpected.when I click`Next` button, I found an error. I was searching for the same question in StackOverflow but I could not find an expected solution. here is my code:-

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.hellowandroid;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Button falsebutton;
    private Button truebutton;
    private TextView questionTextView;
    private ImageButton nextButton;

    private int currentQuestionIndex = 0;

    private Question[] questionBank = new Question[]
            {       new Question(R.string.question_amendments, false), 
                    new Question(R.string.question_constitution, true),
                    new Question(R.string.question_declaration, true),
                    new Question(R.string.question_independence_rights, true),
                    new Question(R.string.question_religion, true),
                    new Question(R.string.question_government, false),
                    new Question(R.string.question_government_feds, false),
                    new Question(R.string.question_government_senators, true),
            };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        falsebutton = findViewById(R.id.false_button);
        truebutton = findViewById(R.id.true_button);
        questionTextView = findViewById(R.id.answer_text_view);
        nextButton = findViewById (R.id.next_button);


        falsebutton.setOnClickListener(this);
        truebutton.setOnClickListener(this);
        nextButton.setOnClickListener(this);



    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId())

        {
            case R.id.false_button:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"false",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.true_button:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"true",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case R.id.next_button:

                //go to next question
                currentQuestionIndex = (currentQuestionIndex + 1) % questionBank.length; 

                Log.d("Current Index","onClick"+currentQuestionIndex);




             
                questionTextView.setText((questionBank[currentQuestionIndex].getAnswerResId()));


        }

    }
}
```

maybe this line `questionTextView.setText((questionBank[currentQuestionIndex].getAnswerResId()));` has a problem, I am not sure.

Question.java

```
package com.example.hellowandroid;

public class Question {
    private int answerResId;
    private boolean answerTrue;

    public Question (int answerResId,boolean answerTrue)
    {
        answerResId=this.answerResId;
        answerTrue=this.answerTrue;

    }

    public int getAnswerResId() {
        return answerResId;
    }

    public void setAnswerResId(int answerResId) {
        this.answerResId = answerResId;
    }

    public boolean isAnswerTrue() {
        return answerTrue;
    }

    public void setAnswerTrue(boolean answerTrue) {
        this.answerTrue = answerTrue;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/design_default_color_primary_dark"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_dialer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/answer_text_view"
        android:text="@string/question_declaration"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>



    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/true_button"
            android:text="@string/true_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/false_button"
            android:text="@string/false_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>




    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:contentDescription="@string/next_text"
        android:id="@+id/next_button"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>



    
</LinearLayout>
```

strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">HellowAndroid</string>

    <string name="true_text">true</string>
    <string name="false_text">false</string>
    <string name="question_declaration">General Knowledge Of US Students.</string>
    <string name="correct_answer">That\'s correct</string>
    <string name="wrong_answer">That\'s incorrect</string>
    <string name="question_constitution">The Supreme law of the land is the Constitution.</string>
    <string name="question_amendments">The (U.S.) Constitution has 26 Amendments.</string>
    <string name="question_independence_rights">The two rights in the Declaration of Independence are:
        \n \t <b>life</b> \n  \t <b>pursuit of happiness</b>.</string>
    <string name="question_religion">Freedom of religion means:
        \n \t <b>You can practice any religion, or not practice a religion</b>.</string>
    <string name="question_government">Journalists is one branch or part of the government.</string>
    <string name="question_government_feds">Congress does not make federal laws.</string>
    <string name="question_government_senators">There are one hundred (100) U.S. Senators.</string>
    <string name="next_text">next</string>

</resources>
```

Here is the error:-

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.hellowandroid, PID: 27079
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:1184)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5218)
        at com.example.hellowandroid.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:81)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6312)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23985)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6816)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1563)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1451)
```

also i tried `questionTextView.setText(""+ questionBank[currentQuestionIndex]. getAnswerResId());` but same error. it's main is mainly happend when i click next button.how i resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set these variables the wrong way.

```java
public Question (int answerResId, boolean answerTrue)
{
  answerResId = this.answerResId;
  answerTrue = this.answerTrue;
}
```

It should have been like this:

```java
public Question (int answerResId, boolean answerTrue)
{
  this.answerResId = answerResId;
  this.answerTrue = answerTrue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of `currentQuestionIndex` must be smaller than the value of `questionBank.size()`:

```
if (currentQuestionIndex >= questionBank.size()) {
   throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(
       "no item exists at index " + currentQuestionIndex
   );
}
```

And I really do not understand the purpose of this `%` modulo operation here:

```
currentQuestionIndex = (currentQuestionIndex + 1) % questionBank.length;
```

The common way of writing that might rather be:

```
currentQuestionIndex ++;
```

Comment: Now i found an error now ```can not find symbol method size()```

Comment: I am use ```currentQuestionIndex = (currentQuestionIndex + 1) % questionBank.length;``` instead ```currentQuestionIndex ++;``` because when my questionindex>questionSize then automaticly currentQuestion start from 0.

Comment: With an array, that may be `.lenght()` (just use an ArrayList, as anybody else and the code would work). And your business logic provides no sense, as the error clearly shows. It's almost funny how you point out one minor typo, while presenting code that just doesn't work. Do you want to tell me, that your code is correct?

Comment: Thanks, problem solved.